# Flask app not running on development configuration

Tags: python, flask, configuration

i am running a flask application, the app is running but not following the configurations i have set.This is the config file

```
import os

class Config(object):
    "parent configuration class"
    DEBUG= True



class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    "Configurations for Development"
    DEBUG = True
    connectionVariables="dbname='store-manager' user='postgres' password="1235" host='localhost' port='5432'"
    os.environ['ENVIRONMENT']='development'

class TestingConfig(Config):
    """Configurations for Testing,"""
    TESTING = True
    DEBUG = True
    connectionVariables="dbname='store-manager-test' user='postgres' password="1235" host='localhost' port='5432'"
    os.environ['ENVIRONMENT']='testing'


app_config = {
    'development': DevelopmentConfig,
    'testing': TestingConfig
}
```

Whenever i run the app it runs on testing mode even when i have specified development, however, if i remove the testing configuration, it runs on development environment.
This is how am creating the app

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api

from instance.config import app_config
from connection import DbBase



def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])


    return app
```

This is how am running it.

```
import os
from app import create_app

config_name = 'development'

app = create_app(config_name)
# method to run app.py
if __name__ == '__main__':


    app.run()
```

Comment: What's the full name of your config file? development.cfg?

Comment: i have named it config.py

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you're actually running it and on what platform, you need to be sure to specify the location of the config.file.

```
export YOURAPPLICATION_SETTINGS=/path/to/settings.cfg
```

or for windows

```
set YOURAPPLICATION_SETTINGS=\path\to\settings.cfg
```

I'm not seeing it in the above description, so this may the the problem.

[Flask Doc on using a config File](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/#configuring-from-files)